# Descargar en CSV o Excel de un resultado json desde python

Tags: python, json, excel, csv

me encuentro accediendo a los datos de una página de facebook utilizando su API, ya obtuve un resultado pero es una salida en Json, quisiera poder descargar esa data en una tabla CSV o EXCEL

```
    import requests
    import facebook
    import urllib3
    
    token= 'EAAM8SW6f934BAAjhZASTjC0ZAQcpelSruBUvz0LORZAri26cRo2CpM74d3QecOuJhOwZCJBBOID0SbM9AC3suYlBTP84jMEjtb3WAgy1j5jX6pCmlcbNwBcai7eoKZAWCZA1FZCLjWfNOlsukjfUiM4WZCly0yLwgeCA5onNlKaMFBXq5Pn8js45NqU46LgoUOL2tlE58yenUwZDZD'
    
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token)
    events = graph.request('/183250211597/insights?metric=page_fans%2Cpage_actions_post_reactions_total%2Cpage_impressions%2Cpage_views_total&period=day&date_preset=last_year')
```

el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

[image: output]

alguno me podría dar una idea de como puedo convertir ese resdultado en una salida CSV o Excel?

Comment: Que has intentado? Si demuestras que eres parte del esfuerzo por responder tu propia duda (por ejemplo, agregando tu intento de convertirlo a csv o  excel) tu pregunta será mejor recibida y no parecerá del tipo "haganme la tarea". Además, sin saber la salida esperada, es imposible responder.

Comment: Puedes usar modulos hechos para escribir csvs y xlsx, como csv(parte de la librería estandar, no hace falta instalarla) y openpyxl respectivamente.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Utilice el csvmódulo para convertir JSON en un archivo CSV**

En este método, usaremos la csvbiblioteca en Python que se usa para leer y escribir archivos CSV. Primero, leeremos los datos JSON como hicimos en el método anterior. Abrimos un archivo en el modo de escritura y usamos el DictWriter()del csvmódulo para crear un objeto que nos permita mapear y escribir datos JSON en el archivo. Son fieldnamesclaves que se identifican y combinan con los datos cuando escribimos filas usando la writerows()función.

El siguiente fragmento de código mostrará cómo podemos implementar el método anterior:

```
import csv
import json

data = '''
{
"Results":
         [
         { "id": "1", "Name": "Jay" },
         { "id": "2", "Name": "Mark" },
         { "id": "3", "Name": "Jack" }
         ],
"status": ["ok"]
}
'''

info = json.loads(data)['Results']

print(info[0].keys())

with open("samplecsv.csv", 'w') as f: 
    wr = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = info[0].keys()) 
    wr.writeheader() 
    wr.writerows(info)
```

**Use el método Pandas DataFrames to_csv()para convertir JSON a CSV en Python**

En este método, primero convertiremos el JSON en un Pandas DataFrame y desde allí lo convertiremos en un archivo CSV usando el to_csv()método. Podemos leer la cadena JSON usando la json.loads()función que se proporciona en la jsonbiblioteca de Python para convertir JSON en un DataFrame. Luego pasamos este objeto JSON a la json_normalize()función que devolverá un Pandas DataFrame que contiene los datos requeridos.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = '''
{
"Results":
         [
         { "id": "1", "Name": "Jay" },
         { "id": "2", "Name": "Mark" },
         { "id": "3", "Name": "Jack" }
         ],
"status": ["ok"]
}
'''

info = json.loads(data)

df = pd.json_normalize(info['Results'])

df.to_csv("samplecsv.csv")
```

Comment: Podrías colocar la información más importante del link en la respuesta por favor? Si el link se cae, la respuesta se volverá inutil para futuros lectores.